# How do we implement Overlaying?

Tags: embedded

Overlay enables a process to cheat the system into thinking it is contained in the memory allotted to it; but at the same time be able to be many times the space allotted. This is what I understand about overlays.

How are they implemented in real life scenarios(esp. Embedded Systems) ?

Comment: You have one close vote for lack of clarity, and another for excessive breadth.  You could improve this question and possibly avoid closure by being more specific with respect to one or more of architecture, target platform, tool-chain, programming language etc.  Alternatively narrow the scope somewhat by specifying some "real life scenarios" you are thinking of - that part is particularly open and vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Embedded Systems" is a broad domain, and I suspect there is no "one answer" covering *all* embedded system scenarios.

For starters overlaying is unnecessary for systems with an MMU and therefore able to support virtual memory.  On such targets one would normally deploy an OS capable or performing the virtual memory management more or less transparently.

In the case common to many embedded systems that code runs entirely from ROM, overlays are not applicable at all.

Both virtual memory and overlay techniques are unsuited to many embedded systems in any case where hard real-time deterministic behaviour is required.

For overlays to make any sense you need an architecture capable of running code from RAM and a mass storage system for storing the overlay code segments.  In software terms you need linker support for overlays and an *overlay manager* in your embedded code image for ARM and using the ARM RealView toolchain (and therefore also applicable to Keil tools) an example can be found [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4234.html), with more linker detail [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0101a/armlink_cchihacc.htm)

Ultimately you use overlays to solve a problem that is best avoided in the frst instance.  It may be necessary for implementing large applications on constrained legacy hardware, but you would not want to design-in such a constraint from the start - if this is for a new hardware design, design hardware with sufficient memory in the first instance.

Another development that may make overlays unnecessary is QSPI "Execute in-place".  Microcontrollers from at least [Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-44065-Execute-in-Place-XIP-with-Quad-SPI-Interface-SAM-V7-SAM-E7-SAM-S7_Application-Note.pdf) and [ST](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/b0/7e/46/a8/5e/c1/48/01/DM00227538/files/DM00227538.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00227538.pdf) support this technology that allows memory-mapped read-only and excute access to memory on a QSPI port rather then the address/data bus.  Since often a similar memory device might be used to contain overlays in any case, the use of QSPI is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Your statement "For overlays to make any sense you need an architecture capable of running code from RAM ...and mass storage" - is simply not true. Yes, that is a usecase for overlays, but not the only one, yet your statement allows no other. As per the example in my answer, overlays can be implemented completely in ROM for code running from ROM, and in fact for what I'd called "classic" embedded systems, i.e. the space you say "...code runs entirely from ROM, overlays are not applicable at all" this may be the more likely way of running overlays if the CPU is truly hardware limited.

Comment: Your answer focusses on one particular aspect of overlays, no problem with that, but you have also excluded the possibility of others, and that exclusion is not correct, is too simplistic.

Comment: @barny : I think we'll have to agree to disagree; I do not accept that *memory paging* is at all related to *overlaying* and all the material I accessed to research my answer bares that out.  I am of course willing to concede your point if there were a convincing citation.  I can see that memory paging bares some similarities or overlaying, but it is not the same and does not address the same problem - in paging, the code is executed in place, and the memory map moves, whereas in overlaying the code is moved *into* the memory map from non-memory mapped media.

Comment: Note that the overlay storage need not be non-memory mapped as in the previous comment; there is a use case for loading overlays from ROM to RAM where RAM execution might be considerably faster, but the RAM insufficient to hold all code at one time.  Tuning performance in such a case however remains tricky.  The point is the code is *moved* into RAM rather then executed in-place.

Comment: Why the noise about paging? Overlaying is replacing a code area of CPU address space with different code linked to run in the same address range. Wikipedia talks about "loading" an overlay, mostly in the context of non-embedded systems (mainframes, CP/M, ...) The way an overlay is "loaded" doesn't _require_ reading code from disk into RAM, that is simply one way of achieving the effect of overlaying. Loading can just as easily be achieved by writing to a register which selects a ROM bank visible in an address space. Citation: The 64180/Z180 CPU memory architecture, and first-hand experience.

Comment: Like I said - we should probably agree to differ.  Although that is not a "citation" by any definition.  I understand the mechanism, and too have first hand experience of it, and the term used for that in Z180 is "bank switching" or "code banking" not overlaying.  The code does not move in bank-switching, the memory map does.  It requires the exact amount of physical address-mappable memory as the size of the code; overlaying does not, and so addresses a significantly different problem (or in some cases the same problem by different means - depending on what your actual problem was).

Comment: Citation for Z180 & term "Code Banking" and also "Memory Paging" in the context I used the term (i.e. not virtual memory paging): http://www.zilog.com/docs/z180/softools.pdf

Answer (score 3):

"How are they implemented...?"

Very carefully. Don't go there voluntarily - I doubt you would need to these days with 32-bit CPUs common in embedded systems.

You wouldn't implement overlays by choice - they are IMO a desperate workaround when your CPU's basic address space (or physical memory accessible to the CPU) isn't large enough to contain all the code or data you need to accommodate, and you need careful hardware and software design to support the implementation.

Why would you need to use what I have called desperate methods? Perhaps because you already have a stable/large investment in a CPU-specific architecture yet your code needs are outgrowing it.

I will discuss here an example of ROM-based embedded system where code has outgrown the memory space of the core CPU in what I'd loosely describe as a "classic" embedded system, where code runs entirely from ROM, RAM is also limited and there is no mass storage. There are of course other scenarios in larger-scale embedded systems which run from RAM and even have mass storage.

In a ROM-based embedded system, the hardware design might provide for a fixed bank of code, a fixed bank of RAM (i.e. both non-overlaid) and the one or more windows in the memory space where what is visible in that window is selected from larger ROM/RAM storage areas by outputting a bank number to some dedicated memory mapping registers. Visible through those windows might be ROM and RAM but unless you want to make things very difficult for yourself you dedicate to one or the other.

Occasionally you will find a CPU which implements hardware to support this. A long time ago I used the Hitachi 64180 which was a Z80 (which has a 16-bit memory addressing architecture) with added memory mapping hardware to allow mapping into a 1Mbyte physical memory space - that was an exciting and almost unimaginable amount of address space at the time. You could fairly easily have implemented a simple (less-general purpose) overlaid memory management with chips external to a Z80.

Why did Zilog/Hitachi bother 35-ish years ago to produce a Z80 with memory mapping hardware? Because they had a large existing market share in Z80 (which itself was based on the Intel 8080) and by this desperate workaround could offer their customers a way to write larger code without throwing away their existing Z80-based code and starting again. I think they succeeded as well as they could - the 64180 works, and also their customers didn't have any other ways of breaking through the 64kbyte barrier.

In a similar position maybe 50 years ago, Digital Equipment Corporation had a highly-successful PDP-11 range of 16-bit processors and wanted to hold onto their customers by offering a migration path, so they implemented similar hardware overlay management to expand from 64kbyte to 256kbyte addressing. It worked for a few years, but you wouldn't choose to start any new design on that sort of platform, not if you had any choice.

Your code has to be very carefully laid out if part of it is overlaid - interrupt routines must always be in the fixed bank because they may be invoked at any time. Common routines should also be always present, and in the overlaid segments you have to ensure either that there are no inter-overlay calls, or that your compiler makes those calls and the returns from them through code in the fixed bank which switches the overlaid bank between the desired overlays. Similarly in RAM, the stack has to be always in the fixed RAM bank, and you have to be careful that RAM references into a banked window are made correctly - simplest if only one bit of code refers into the banked RAM area.

Overlays aren't nice. You end up doing a lot of engineering work just to make the overlays work. Overlay-related bugs can be very difficult to pin down and debug because they can be very transient. My advice is: don't go there unless you are backed in a corner.

(edited to add more background that this is a description of overlays in a ROM-based embedded system)

Comment: Is the discussion of the 64180/Z180 paged memory architecture relevant to the question?  In that case it is a matter of a larger *physical memory* than the *core architecture address space*; whereas overlays deal with a different problem of a larger application than physical *random-access* memory.

Comment: The relevance is that a) the OP asked "how are overlays implemented?" and b) this is an example of how overlays are implemented in a ROM-based embedded system, and while yes the more general statement that overlays deal with "the problem of a larger application than the ... physical memory" is true, the example where physical memory takes up ALL the available memory space is valid within that statement. I'm using the 64180 as a real, concrete example.

Comment: My point was that *memory paging* is not the same thing as *overlaying*, and certainly not what the question refers to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_(programming).  In any case if it were a hardware technique it would be off-topic for SO.

Comment: If *paging* is an option, then *overlaying* may be unnecessary, but they nonetheless remain different concepts.  It might be valid to suggest it as an alternative for consideration, but not as an answer to the question perhaps.

Comment: Note that the term "paging" is used also to refer to virtual memory swapping; that is not the sense in which I am using it in the previous comment.  The technique is also referred to as *"code banking"* or "bank switching".  Terms are often overloaded in software and computing, but I can find no reference to bank switching being referred to as *overlaying* - happy to be proven incorrect, but mere opinion won't sway me.

Comment: You introduced the term paging in your first comment - I never used it because that's not what I'm talking about. I agree that paging is probably not in scope because as the wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging states, it is about virtual memory and I think that is only likely to be relevant on the distant upper tail of the embedded systems characteristics bell-curve - but someone might think that their system which uses virtual memory paging is an embedded system, so I wouldn't simply exclude.

Comment: Let's focus on the what overlaying does, looking at code.  Let's imagine a code area which has code linked to run at the those addresses. Overlaying replaces the contents of that area of with different code linked to run in that same range of address. However the term 'overlaying' doesn't state HOW that effect is achieved. You seem to be keen to assert that the process of replacing the code requires the address range to be in RAM, and requires the replacing code to come from mass storage. I agree that your use case  is one type of overlaying, but only one type, not the only one.

Comment: Specifically, the effect of overlaying (i.e. replacing an area of code with different code linked to run at those same addresses) can also be achieved by hardware bank switching, and an example is the 64180 memory addressing architecture. Further, that need have nothing to do mass storage and  execution from RAM.

Comment: The term 'embedded system' refers to a spectrum of designs which may run entirely from on-chip code in ROM using very limited on-chip RAM, to designs which copy code from ROM or mass-storage into RAM for execution. I am sure your example is valid, but it is only _one_ example, not the _only_ example, of how overlays are implemented. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by repeatedly stating that your answer is the only way overlays are implemented, because that is simply not correct.

Comment: Bank switching has the same effect as your description of overlaying. It walks the same, it quacks the same. Indistinguishable in end effect from your fixation on 'reading from mass storage into RAM' overlaying, bank switching is one way of implementing overlays, just as reading from disk into RAM is another way. Bank switching could even be used with pre-loaded RAM, too, making the duck-typing even quackier.

Comment: Here's another way to look at this discussion. If I use a CP/M overlay linker to carefully produce executable fixed-address binary (as used by CP/M) code in an overlaid memory organisation with specific overlaid area memory address ranges to run from RAM, as described in the wikipedia article, I don't see how you could disagree that I am using overlays. (Continued in next comment)

Comment: (Continued from previous comment)  Now, if I carefully burn that same executable binary into ROM, and instead of dynamically reading overlays off floppy disk, I dynamically write to a register to select the ROM bank visible in the overlay area, I assert that I am still using overlays. Bank switching is used to achieve the effect of overlays, instead of reading from mass storage to achieve the effect of overlays, and the code may execute from ROM or RAM, and they are both examples of using overlays. Quack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128691/discussion-between-clifford-and-barny).

Comment: Wow!  No further discussion; the reader can decide and take what they need from this.